# Most frequent substring of fixed length - simple solution needed

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

> Please describe (without implementation!) algorithm (possibly fastest)
>   which receives string of n letters and positive integer k as
>   arguments, and prints the most frequent substring of length k (if
>   there are multiple such substrings, algorithm prints any one of them).
>   String is composed of letters "a" and "b". For example: for string
>   ababaaaabb and k=3 the answer is "aba", which occurs 2 times (the fact
>   that they overlap doesn't matter). Describe an algorithm, prove its
>   correctness and calculate its complexity.

I can use only most basic functions of C++: no vectors, classes, objects etc. I also don't know about strings, only char tables. Can someone please explain to me what the algorithm would be, possibly with implementation in code for easier understanding? That's question from university exam, that's why it's so weird.

Comment: It's unclear how you get from that description to C++ or this mysterious C/C++ (which doesn't exist) that you are referring to.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: early C++ implementations were built in C code by means of macros.

Comment: That is historically relevant, @YvesDaoust, but even twenty years ago you already had native C++ compilers. And still, what is the precise meaning of C/C++? IMHO it's just handwaving done by people that don't understand that these are two different programming languages.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I am sure this problem can be solved with code that will work both under a C and a C++ compiler.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that was bad way to write it, all my professors write it that way. It means C or C++, because there is assumption that in this course our programs are so simple they are basically almost the same in both languages (since we're not allowed to use more advanced features of C++ like objects).

Comment: @Biffen: for such algorithmic problems, object orientation adds little benefits, if it is not harmful by introducing hidden costs in constructors/operators and the like. (The worst being invisible dynamic allocations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is by trying all possible substrings from left to right (i.e. starting from indices `i=0` to `n-k`), and comparing each to the next substrings (i.e. starting from indices `j=i+1` to `n-k`).

For every `i`-substring, you count the number of occurrences, and keep a trace of the most frequentso far.

As a string comparison costs at worst k character comparisons, and you will be performing `(n-k-1)(n-k)/2` such comparisons and the total cost is of order `O(k(n-k)²)`. [In fact the cost can be lower because some of the string comparisons may terminate early, but I an not able to perform the evaluation.]

This solution is simple but probably not efficient.

In theory you can reduce the cost using a more efficient string matching algorithm, such as Knuth-Morris-Pratt, resulting in `O((n-k)(n+k))` operations.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's first helpful answer here and it's all I need.